# The entity type requires a primary key to be defined error with key attribute

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio-2017, entity-framework-core, primary-key

Setting up a proof of concept app. I've added an `ApplicationDbContext` class and my `Transaction` class to the `Web Application (Model-View-Controller)` template in VS2017.

When I try to run `Add-Migration AddsTransactions` I get this error:

> The entity type 'Transaction' requires a primary key to be defined.

Here's my `ApplicationDbContext`:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Transactions;

namespace WebApplication4.Data
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Transaction> Transactions { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And my `Transaction` model class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WebApplication4.Models
{
    public class Transaction
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTimeOffset TransactionDate { get; set; }
        public decimal TransactionAmount { get; set; }

        public bool OnHold
        {
            get { return this.FundingStatus == FundingStatus.Held; }
            set { this.FundingStatus = FundingStatus.Held; }
        }

        public FundingStatus FundingStatus { get; set; }
    }

    public enum FundingStatus
    {
        New,
        Submitted,
        Funded,
        Held
    }
}
```

From what I've read, Entity Framework Core *should* see that I have a property named `Id` and make that my primary key and, if for some weird reason it didn't do this, the `[Key]` attribute should force it to be a primary key.

Unfortunately, reality seems to be disagreeing with me. Any ideas?

Comment: What version of EF are you using? The enum requires attribute, I believe, in early versions of EF. I think EF5 and up this should be ok as you have it. It may be that the EF is what's throwing the exception. Also, I've personally never seen the get / set have conditions for EF code first, but that's not saying it can't. My experience has just never involved it.

Comment: @MichaelPuckettII I'm using Entity Framework Core 2.0.2

Answer (score 2):

Today's lesson is "Don't just click on the first thing Intellisense give you, especially when using vague class names"

Turns out I did not want `using System.Transactions;`, I wanted `using WebApplication4.Models` in my `ApplicationDbContext` file.